# MongoDB Authentication failed in robotframework

Tags: mongodb, robotframework

I tried to connect and authenticate mongodb through robotframework.
followed the following steps:

```
Connect To MondoDB | mongodb://admin:admin@192.20.33.226 | 27017 | 10 | None | <type 'dict'> | False |
```

Sucessfully connected.

Tried to query from database

```
Retrieve Mongodb Records With Desired Fields     dbName | dbCollName | recordJSON | fields | return__id=True | returnDocuments=False
```

after execution of this statement, i got the following error.

```
OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
```

log:

```
Starting test: MongoConnection.Query from MongoDB
20161209 17:05:05.866 :  INFO : 
| Connect To MondoDB | dbHost | dbPort | dbMaxPoolSize | dbNetworktimeout | dbDocClass | dbTZAware |
| Connect To MondoDB | mongodb://tecnotree:tecnotree@172.20.33.226 | 27017 | 10 | None | <type 'dict'> | False |
20161209 17:05:05.907 :  INFO : | ${allResults} | retreive_mongodb_records_with_desired_fields | clmpreprod | Profile | { "profileDetails.basicDetails.customerCode": "C014519" } | profileDetails.customerCategory.masterCode,profileDetails.customerSubCategory.masterCode | False |
20161209 17:05:05.910 :  FAIL : OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
Ending test:   MongoConnection.Query from MongoDB
```

I sat with my MongoDB database analysit and debugged, we comes to know that, first it tried to connect to adminDB with the user credentials given and at the time of query it connected to actual db.

here, in our system credentials for admin db and system db are different, that's why it failed.

our db analyst confirmed that , they will not allow to connect to admin db as it will have all permissions.

can any one help me , how to connect and query from mongodb which will not connect to admin db.

Thanks
Sarada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the drivers support the same style of connection string, so you should be able to append the following query things to your current connection string:

`mongodb://username:password@host/database?authSource=authDatabase`

See

- https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#auth-options
- or
- http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html?highlight=url#delegated-authentication

Comment: hi kevin, i have tried as `mongodb://172.20.33.226/clmpreprod?authSource=clmpreprod;` but where to give username and password? there is no separate way to connect to db and authenticate, it giving error while querying as `perationFailure: database error: not authorized for query on clmpreprod.Profile`

Comment: You need to just add that to the URI, I've updated the answer

Comment: Thanks kevin, `https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#auth-options` ur helped me

Answer (score 0):

you should mention dbname also at the time connecting

```
    Connect To MondoDB | mongodb://admin:admin@192.20.33.216/userDB | 27017 | 10 | None | <type 'dict'> | False 

Retrieve Mongodb Records With Desired Fields     dbName | dbCollName | recordJSON | fields | return__id=True | returnDocuments=False
```

This will work

Thanks Kevin for your help